# haskell Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Text' with actual type `Text'

Tags: haskell

full code https://github.com/gertcuykens/haskell-design

How can i lift Maybe from Maybe Text type

```
application :: MVar ServerState -> WS.Request -> WS.WebSockets WS.Hybi10 ()
application state rq = do
    WS.acceptRequest rq
    WS.getVersion >>= liftIO . putStrLn . ("Client version: " ++)
    sink <- WS.getSink
    msg <- WS.receiveData
    clients <- liftIO $ readMVar state
    url <- liftIO fbUrl

    let prefix = "Facebook code"
    let code = T.drop (T.length prefix) msg

    let a = ("code",T.unpack code)
    e <- liftIO $ fbEmail $ (\(x,y) -> (C.pack x, C.pack y)) a

    let client = (e, sink) --ERROR

    case msg of
        _   | not (prefix `T.isPrefixOf` msg) -> do
                WS.sendTextData ("Facebook login " `mappend` url :: Text)
            | any ($ fst client)
                [T.null, T.any isPunctuation, T.any isSpace] ->
                    WS.sendTextData ("Facbook code invalid" :: Text)
            | clientExists client clients ->
                WS.sendTextData ("User already exists" :: Text)
            | otherwise -> do
                liftIO $ modifyMVar_ state $ \s -> do
                    let s' = addClient client s
                    WS.sendSink sink $ WS.textData $
                        "Welcome! Users: " `mappend`
                        T.intercalate ", " (map fst s)
                    broadcast (fst client `mappend` " joined") s'
                    return s'
                talk state client

    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Text' with actual type `Text'
    Expected type: Maybe Text -> Bool
      Actual type: Text -> Bool
    In the expression: T.null
    In the second argument of `any', namely
      `[T.null, T.any isPunctuation, T.any isSpace]'
```

Comment: for all the down voters out there I don't mind your vote I mind you not leaving a comment about what you do not like. Some people like complete code examples other short. And in my case the short extraction does not make any sense most of the time.

Comment: if you can't reproduce the problem in a smaller code sample, then how much help will that be for the next person who thinks they have the same problem you do? Stack Overflow is not just for you, it's for everyone that has your issue.  If you aren't able to communicate succicintly, you aren't going to be much help to the next person. Pay it forward, take the time to pare down your issue to its essentials. Also: Links die, move, and otherwise become broken. If your question can't stand on its own, that's another problem.

Comment: The next person that can extract a easy haskell question out of this will not need stackoverflow anyway :) I will use stackoverflow chat next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [`fbEmail`](https://github.com/gertcuykens/haskell-design/blob/master/Login.hs#L25) function returns a `Maybe Text`. If you expect it to always be a `Just`, you could use a pattern on the left hand side of the variable binding to get the `Text` from it:

```
Just email <- liftIO . fbEmail $ both C.pack a
```

With the following helper to improve readability:

```
both :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
both f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

This ignores errors, however, so you ought to use one of the `Data.Maybe` functions such as `fromMaybe` or `maybe`. Alternatively, you could also use an explicit `case` expression:

```
maybeEmail <- ...
case maybeEmail of
  Just email -> ...  -- Do something with "email".
  Nothing ->    ...  -- Handle missing emails.
```

If you don’t need to do different things in the caller based on whether `fbEmail` returned a `Nothing` or `Just`, you can (and should) move this logic into `fbEmail` itself.

Comment: from irc haskell `Just e <- liftIO $ fbEmail $ (\(x,y) -> (C.pack x, C.pack y)) a` seems easier to read

Comment: can you add a `case` example pleas?